# How to loop array inside object vue.js

Tags: javascript, api, loops, for-loop, vue.js

I have a question regarding looping through some data retrieved from an API using a `GET` fetch within Vue.js.

This is the response from the route:

```
"data": {
     "Orders": [
               {
            "OrderID": 1,
            "Ordered_Products": {
                            "items": [
                                         {
                                    "id": 2,
                                    "title": "Hildegard Prohaska",
                                    "quantity": 5,
                                    },
                                    {
                                    "id": 3,
                                    "title": "Odell Zieme",
                                    "quantity": 3,
                                    }
                                ]
                               },
            "Pay_method": 1,
            //stuff
       },
    {
            "OrderID": 1,
            "Ordered_Products": {
                            "items": [
                                         {
                                    "id": 2,
                                    "title": "Hildegard Prohaska",
                                    "quantity": 2,
                                    },
                                    {
                                    "id": 3,
                                    "title": "Odell Zieme",
                                    "quantity": 1,
                                    }
                                ]
                               },
            "Pay_method": 2,
            //stuff
       }
   ]
}
```

And here is my fetch:

```
methods: {
    fetchOrders () {
      fetch('https://myapidomine.com')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
          this.orders = res.data.Orders
        })
    }
  }
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
<v-card flat v-for="order in orders" :key="order.OrderID">
        <v-layout row wrap">
          <v-flex xs12 md4>
            <div class="caption grey--text">PayMethod</div>
            <div>{{ order.Pay_method }}</div>
          </v-flex>
```

If I access to a key inside `Orders`, like `{{order.Pay_method}}` works fine, and that loop is working fine, but I need to loop the items inside `Ordered_Products.items` and use `title`, etc...

If I do:

```
<v-list-item-title xs12 md3>{{order.Ordered_Products.items[0].title}}
```

I get the data fine, but of course just of the first product, but not sure how can I loop that data

Thank you in advance, (I'm new in vue)

Comment: Check docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: Have you tried simply `<v-list-item-title xs12 md3 v-for="item in order.Ordered_Products.item">{{item.title}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see your whole code but something like this would do:

```
<v-list-item-title xs12 md3 :key="index" v-for="(item, index) in order.Ordered_Products.items">
   {{item.title}}
</v-list-item-title>
```